# CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION not updated for new kernel

Tags: cmake

I use cmake to install a linux driver. To get the kernel version I use [`CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION.html) which should yield the output of `uname -r`.

However, after I installed a new kernel, I tried to reinstall the driver with cmake, just to note that it was installing to `/lib/modules/<previous kernel>/...` rather than to the directory for the current kernel. `uname- r` gives the correct result.

I use the following line in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
install(PROGRAMS myDevice.ko DESTINATION "/lib/modules/${CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION}/kernel/drivers/myDevice" COMPONENT driver)
```

I could not find CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION in the CMakeCache.txt, and just rerunning `cmake ..` did not do the trick either. I had to regenerate the entire build folder.

I would like to know if there is a better way, since the build folder also contains applications, that should not need rebuilding, just because there is a new kernel.

Comment: What's your CMake version? I think it has changed it's behavior, check out the latest documentation of CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION.html

Comment: @usr1234567 the version is 3.5.2. I did not set the variable explicitly so it should become `CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_VERSION` which should be `uname -r`. And I don't find `CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_VERSION` in CMakeCache.txt either, so it should still represent the current kernel version, right?

Comment: @usr1234567 Yes it should: the documentation (that you point to) states that `CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION` defaults to [`CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_VERSION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/variable/CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_VERSION.html#variable:CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_VERSION) which is `uname -r`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are CMake variables, which are fixed since the first configuration. *CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION* is one of them. *CMAKE_C_COMPILER* is another example of "fixed" variables: changing it invalidates cache completely.

So, you need to make different builds for different kernels.

You may separate configuration and building of user-space application from kernel modules. So rebuilding kernel module doesn't force rebuilding of the applications.

Exactly that approach I have used in my projects: setting one option (introduced with `option()` command) builds only applications, setting another option builds only kernel modules. By default, none option is set and both kernel-space and user-space components are built.